# Beep recognition recorded my mic android

Tags: java, android

I am looking for an easy way to detect beep recorded by mic on android. Have to detect long beep sound . What could be the possible ways ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is for her to broad but I will try to explain the steps that you need to follow.

First you need to use Android's API to monitor the sound input through the microhpone, this means recording continuously into some circular buffer.

The next step is passing samples from this circular buffer to a piece of code that analyzes these samples and extract frequency information from the samples. Usually this code uses some kind of FFT, and because of the amount of math and processing involved it's usually written in C, and interfaced using the NDK. There are some libraries out there that do this but I haven't used them, for example, FFMPEG.

Once have the frequencies of the sample you can compare them to the beep of the sound you are expecting.